# Loop not running when trying to implement a UDP windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to write a Windows service to receive data over a UDP port. (The program works as a stand alone windows console application). The DoWork() method contains the loop waiting for data to come through UDP, however the log file AuthService.txt is never updated from the DoWork method. Any ideas?? Thanks

```
class AccessControlService : ServiceBase
{
    static void Main()
    {
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new AccessControlService() };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }

    public void InitilizeComponent()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "ACS";
    }

    private string folderPath = @"C:\Temp\";

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "\\AuthService.txt",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        StreamWriter m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
        m_streamwriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamwriter.WriteLine("Access control service started at " + 
            DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + 
            DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "\n");
        m_streamwriter.Flush();
        m_streamwriter.Close();

        DoWork();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "\\AuthService.txt",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

        StreamWriter m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
        m_streamwriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamwriter.WriteLine("Access control service stopped at " + 
            DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + 
            DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "\n");
        m_streamwriter.Flush();
        m_streamwriter.Close();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // 
        // AccessControlService
        // 
        this.ServiceName = "AccessControlService";
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
        UdpClient newsock = new UdpClient(ipep);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect on port 8888...");

        IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        while (true)
        {
            data = newsock.Receive(ref sender);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(folderPath + "\\AuthService.txt",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            StreamWriter m_streamwriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamwriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamwriter.WriteLine("UDP Data received");
            m_streamwriter.Flush();
            m_streamwriter.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you never start your timer running so your DoWork method would never get called.

Comment: I am curious why the fourth parameter of constructor of the timer is 5000, do you need start DoWork every 5 seconds? And I suggest you add a try-catch block in DoWork, I think there may be an exception, and since it is runing in a minor thread, it fails silently.

Comment: I have since removed the timer as It was just something I found on another post. I am not sure how to initialize the DoWork() method within a Windows Service though.

Comment: You can start DoWork in another thread. Try `new Action(DoWork).BeginInvoke();`. And don't forget add a try-catch block in DoWork.